# fixed font size not affected by zoom in or out

Tags: css

How can I make a fixed font size not affected by zoom in or out?
I have tried using `font-size: 100%;` but when I zoom in or out the font size doesn't remain 100%, it keeps changing.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the user from changing your text size? This is a usability item that some people may need to watch your site.

Comment: @TeeDeJee I want to use it just in fullscreen mode, if the user zooms in or out the font size will change and this changing will affect the position of other elements.

Comment: You have 2 choices: to disable zoom (prevent keydown event) or to rescale your text when zoomed.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto looks like I have to disable zoom. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You may use following css attribute. With all the browser prefixes. But this will only work on some browsers and mostly on mobile browsers.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none
text-size-adjust: none
```

If `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is explicitely set to `none`, Webkit-based desktop and tablet browsers, like Chrome or Safari, instead of ignoring the property, will prevent the user to zoom in or out the Web page.

You can look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust for more info and compatibility.

Comment: I said in my answer that it's mostly for mobile browsers. And not a global solution.